# unable to run spring web app on tomcat (eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat

I Have created a very small spring web app however cannot get it to deploy on tomcat using eclipse. I can see in log that web app gets initalised. However tomcat doesnt actually deploy it and if i try to go to URL i get a 404 error for resource not available. Am i missing something here?

**Web xml**

```
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

       <servlet>
          <servlet-name>MNPUI</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>
             org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
          </servlet-class>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
       </servlet>

       <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>MNPUI</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>

       <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>
                home.jsp
            </welcome-file>
       </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**MNPUI-servlet.xml**

```
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.doyleisgod.mnpui.controllers"/>

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

    </beans>
```

**HomeController**

```
package com.doyleisgod.mnpui.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/home.jsp")
    public String home (ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("message", "Welcome");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**home.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
${message}
</body>
</html>
```

**Eclipse Console log**

```
03-Sep-2014 13:33:11 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Data Protection\Access\Advanced\Wave\Gemalto\Access Client\v5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NTRU Cryptosystems\NTRU TCG Software Stack\bin\;C:\Program Files\NTRU Cryptosystems\NTRU TCG Software Stack\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Users\CD00119621\Desktop\eclipse\eclipse;;.
03-Sep-2014 13:33:11 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MNPUI' did not find a matching property.
03-Sep-2014 13:33:11 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
03-Sep-2014 13:33:11 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
03-Sep-2014 13:33:11 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 681 ms
03-Sep-2014 13:33:11 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
03-Sep-2014 13:33:11 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.37
03-Sep-2014 13:33:14 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
03-Sep-2014 13:33:14 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'MNPUI'
03-Sep-2014 13:33:15 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\CD00119621\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\webapps\docs
03-Sep-2014 13:33:15 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\CD00119621\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\webapps\host-manager
03-Sep-2014 13:33:15 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\CD00119621\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\webapps\manager
03-Sep-2014 13:33:15 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\CD00119621\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\webapps\ROOT
03-Sep-2014 13:33:15 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
03-Sep-2014 13:33:15 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
03-Sep-2014 13:33:15 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3760 ms
```

Comment: Have you tried to see where is your project is deployed ?

Comment: @JavaDev Its being depolyed into the webapps folder of tomcat where the other apps are. After clicking "run on server", i can see the mnpui folder appear in webapps

Comment: what is the url are you tried to access ?

Comment: @javaDev tocat is running locally so URL is http://localhost:8080/MNPUI/

Comment: I think there is some mapping issued tried to directly access  localhost:8080/MNPUI/home.jsp

Comment: Yeah it also returns 404 error. I ssue seems to be that while tomcat sees the MNPUI app and initializes it it doesn't seem to deploy it like it does with other apps. If i go into the tomcat manager i can see the app but there is no option to undeploy it so i guess its not actually deployed.

Comment: Please see my answer below..

Comment: Just spotted this on the console log `INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath`

Comment: I have resolved the issue by rebuilding the class path one by one for each missing jar. now its working ok.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change add below line to web.xml file

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jsp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Most servlet containers have a default mapping from `*.jsp` to their own JSP processor.

[Reference from here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/3957-using-jsp-extension)

Comment: I have another spring project and it has same servlet mapping and it works fine.